# Как правильно прописать nth-child?

Tags: css, scss

Привет всем, хочу cдвинуть текст немного ниже в 3 и 4 с помощью nth-child, что бы не прописывать класс, чего то не получается, просветите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.how_pay {
  .item {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    a {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      bottom: 50px;
      left: 50px;
      font-size: rem-calc(15);
      color: $t-gray;
      font-weight: bolder;
      line-height: 1.1;
      transition: all .25s ease;
      &:hover {
        color: #008932;} 
      }
   }
  .item {
    &:nth-child(3) a, &:nth-child(4) a {
        bottom: 40px;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: html добавьте .

Comment: что значит: _чего то не получается_? В зависимости от имеющейся разметки могут быть разные решения.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно его вообще не прописывать и не пихать absolute'ы куда не следует.

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
  counter-reset: i;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

a:before {
  counter-increment: i;
  content: counter(i);
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a>Выбрать квартиру</a>
  <a>Выбрать способ оплаты</a>
  <a>Заключить договор и оплатить</a>
  <a>Мы готовим все документы</a>
  <a>Вы владелец квартиры</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Это почему? Я так понимаю он хочет подравнять по центральной линии текст, и ваш вариант не прокатит.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, а я понял, что по верхней. Для центральной могу другой вариант предложить.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, добавил ответ с центрированием.

Answer (score 0):

```
.how_pay {
    .item {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 10px 0;
        a {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            width: 120px;
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 50px;
            font-size: rem-calc(15);
            color: $t-gray;
            font-weight: bolder;
            line-height: 1.1;
            transition: all .25s ease;
            &:nth-of-type(3),
            &:nth-of-type(4) {
                bottom: 40px;
            }
            &:hover {
                color: #008932;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

и миксин на rem вот такой красивее будет:

```
@mixin x-rem($property, $values) {
    $base-font-size: 16px;
    $px-values: ();
    $rem-values: ();
    @each $value in $values {
        @if $value==0 or $value==0px {
            $px-values: join($px-values, 0);
            $rem-values: join($rem-values, 0);
        }
        @else if type-of($value)==number and not unitless($value) and (unit($value)==px) {
            $new-rem-value: $value / $base-font-size;
            $px-values: join($px-values, round($value));
            $rem-values: join($rem-values, #{$new-rem-value}rem);
        }
        @else {
            $px-values: join($px-values, round($value * $base-font-size));
            $rem-values: join($rem-values, #{$value}rem);
        }
    }
    #{$property}: $px-values;
    #{$property}: $rem-values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот и вариант с вертикальным центрированием.

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
  counter-reset: i;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:before {
  counter-increment: i;
  content: counter(i);
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
}

div {
  height: 56px;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

div:before, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a><div><span>Выбрать квартиру</span></div></a>
  <a><div><span>Выбрать способ оплаты</span></div></a>
  <a><div><span>Заключить договор и оплатить</span></div></a>
  <a><div><span>Мы готовим все документы</span></div></a>
  <a><div><span>Вы владелец квартиры</span></div></a>
</section>
```

Или так:

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
  counter-reset: i;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0, white 45%, antiquewhite 45%, antiquewhite 100%);
}

a:before {
  counter-increment: i;
  content: counter(i);
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
}

a:after, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a><span>Выбрать квартиру</span></a>
  <a><span>Выбрать способ оплаты</span></a>
  <a><span>Заключить договор и оплатить</span></a>
  <a><span>Мы готовим все документы</span></a>
  <a><span>Вы владелец квартиры</span></a>
</section>
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь!